# ¿Cómo funciona el polyfill?

Tags: javascript, polyfill

En la **MDN**, aparece este código que pertenece al `polyfill` de `Array.prototype.includes`, pero no entiendo mucho su código( sé que includes busca coincidencias como indexOf, pero a diferencia de indexOf, includes si detecta el valor NaN en un array) pero el código del *polyfill* en si no entiendo mucho

**Comente en el codigo lo que no entiendo**

```js
if (!Array.prototype.includes) { // si no tiene el metodo includes
  Array.prototype.includes = function(searchElement /*, fromIndex*/ ) { // creal metodo en el prototipo del array
    'use strict'; // modo estricto
    var O = Object(this); // no entiendo que hace
    var len = parseInt(O.length) || 0; // aqui debe ser un numero por lo cual lo anterior debe ser como crear un objeto con el contexto del array, y edta variable "len" saca el largo del objeto(pero los objetos no tienen largo, entonces seria un array??) y si el largo no edta definido sera 0
    if (len === 0) { // si el largo es 0 retorna falso
      return false;
    }
    var n = parseInt(arguments[1]) || 0; // arguments[1] es el segundo argumento que recibe el metodo, pero que recibe?
    var k; 
    if (n >= 0) { // si el argumento es mayor o igual a 0 que no entiendo para qué
      k = n; // de aqui hacia abajo se me ha hecho muy complicado entenderlo, aun busco que significa todo lo de abajo..
    } else {
      k = len + n;
      if (k < 0) {k = 0;}
    }
    var currentElement;
    while (k < len) {
      currentElement = O[k];
      if (searchElement === currentElement ||
         (searchElement !== searchElement && currentElement !== currentElement)) {
        return true;
      }
      k++;
    }
    return false;
  };
}
```

Comment: Decir que este código está escrito de un modo defensivo es quedarse corto, es casi paranoico las comprobaciones que hace :O

Comment: Empiezas diciendo: En el MDN... ¿podrías añadir la URL de origen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El código es un ejemplo de lo que se llama programación defensiva: haz que tu función/método no lance un error pase lo que pase, reciba el parámetro que reciba. Voy a intentar explicar algunos detalles que pueden resultar un tanto arcanos, pero para empezar voy a poner algunos ejemplos de código que están relacionados con lo que aquí vemos:

Para empezar, esta función se va a añadir al objeto Array, con lo que en su uso normal, el contexto, es decir, `this` será un array. Pero no tiene por qué serlo:

```js
function prueba() {
  console.log('Los parámetros recibidos por esta función son:');
  for (let i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) {
    console.log(arguments[i]);
  }
  console.log('el objeto arguments es un Array? '+ (arguments instanceof Array));
  console.log(arguments.__proto__.constructor);
  //pero podemos usar funciones de array sobre él
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments,item => console.log(item));
}


prueba('hola','mundo',1)
```

Por tanto, lo primero es asegurarse de que tenemos un contexto que sea un objeto y que se comporte como un array:

```
if (!Array.prototype.includes) { // si no tiene el metodo 
  Array.prototype.includes = function(searchElement /*, fromIndex*/ ) {
    'use strict'; // modo estricto
    var O = Object(this);
```

Paremos aquí: `Object(this)` es equivalente a `new Object(this)`, que crea un objeto "wrapper" si `this` no es ya un objeto (`string` no es `String` y `number` no es `Number`, similar a Java y su *autoboxing*, aunque también podemos encontrarnos con `null` o `undefined`, que devuelven un objeto `{}`). Si ya es un objeto, entonces devuelve `this` sin hacer cambios. Sigamos con el código:

```
    var len = parseInt(O.length) || 0;
```

Esta línea tiene su miga: Aunque parezca mentira, la clase Object incluye un atributo `length` que siempre vale 1. Pero como hemos dicho antes, this puede ser cualquier cosa, incluyendo un objeto como

```
var obj= {
  1: 'hola',
  2: 'mundo',
  length: 'molesto?'
}
```

Por lo que tendríamos un atributo `length` que no es un número. La línea anterior lo soluciona, porque `parseInt` devolvería `NaN` en el caso de que el atributo `length` no fuese un número o si lo fuese pero con decimales. `NaN` es "falso", con lo que nos quedaríamos con `0`. Sigamos de nuevo con el código:

```
    if (len === 0) { // si el largo es 0 retorna falso
      return false;
    }

    var n = parseInt(arguments[1]) || 0;
```

Paramos de nuevo:

La función `includes` tiene un segundo parámetro que es opcional: es el índice desde el que empezamos a buscar el elemento que hemos recibido como primer parámetro. De manera similar a la anterior, si no pasamos un parámetro que sea un entero, asumimos que buscamos desde 0. Si fuese un valor negativo, buscamos desde length+n, lo que es comprobado por el siguiente `if`:

```
    var k; 
    if (n >= 0) { 
      k = n; 
    } else {
      k = len + n;
      if (k < 0) {k = 0;}
    }
```

Tras esto, nos queda lo más fácil, que es ir recorriendo el array (o el objeto que parece un array) en busca del elemento, devolviendo `true` si lo hemos encontrado, o `false` en caso contrario.

```
    var currentElement;
    while (k < len) {
      currentElement = O[k];
      if (searchElement === currentElement ||
         (searchElement !== searchElement && currentElement !== currentElement)) {
        return true;
      }
      k++;
    }
    return false;
  };
}
```

Detalle final: ¿Qué es esa condición tan complicada? Resulta que en Javascript hay un valor (`NaN`, Not a number) "incomparable", así que si estamos buscando ese valor lo que se hace es comprobarlo de ese modo.

```js
let notANumber=NaN

let miArray=['hola','otra cosa'];
let miOtroArray=[notANumber,'otra cosa'];

//vamos a comprobar si un elemento está en la primera posición de un array
function estaEnPrimeraPosicion(arr,elem) {
  return arr[0]==elem;
}

//parece que en condiciones normales, funciona
let esta=estaEnPrimeraPosicion(miArray,'hola');
console.log('Está hola en miArray? '+esta);

//comprobamos que NaN != 'hola', como es obvio
esta=estaEnPrimeraPosicion(miOtroArray,'hola');
console.log('Está hola en miOtroArray? '+esta);

//NaN está, deberíamos encontrarlo
esta=estaEnPrimeraPosicion(miOtroArray,notANumber);
console.log('Está NaN en miOtroArray? '+esta);

//No es igual ni a sí mismo!
console.log('Se puede comparar NaN con algo? '+ (notANumber==notANumber))

//solución, si lo que estamos buscando no es igual a sí mismo, es porque
// es NaN, así que comprobamos si el elemento en el array es NaN también,
// comparándolo consigo mismo.
function estaEnPrimeraPosicion2(arr,elem) {
  if(arr[0]==elem) return true;
  if (elem!==elem) { // elem es NaN
     if (arr[0]!==arr[0]) { //la primera posición también es NaN
        return true;
     }
  }
  return false;
}

esta=estaEnPrimeraPosicion2(miOtroArray,notANumber);
console.log('Está NaN en miOtroArray (segundo intento)? '+esta);


//más condensado:
function estaEnPrimeraPosicion3(arr,elem) {
  return (arr[0]==elem || (elem!==elem && arr[0]!==arr[0]));
}

esta=estaEnPrimeraPosicion3(miOtroArray,notANumber);
console.log('Está NaN en miOtroArray (segundo intento, condensado)? '+esta);
```

Comment: Muy buena, solo una duda, que hace en searchElement !== searchElement && currentElement !== currentElement

Comment: Es el detalle final, lo reescribiré para dejarlo más claro

Answer (score 7):

El propósito de la función `includes` de la clase `Array` es informar si un **valor** buscado se encuentra **desde** la posición ingresada hasta el final del **array**. Si la posición ingresada es negativa, se busca desde `posición+longitud_array` hasta el final del *array*.

Hay tres elementos, el `array`, y los dos argumentos. `valor` y `desde`.

```
var array=[2,3,4,5]
var valor=10
var desde=2
array.includes(valor,desde) // false
```

Esta función excluye los valores que se encuentran antes del principio y después del final del `array`, por lo que si hay un valor oculto en la posición `-1` del `array`, devuelve `false` si no lo encuentra dentro del rango mencionado anteriormente.

La funcionalidad de `includes` es un poco diferente en *arrays* y *strings*. Si `desde` es negativo, y es un string, se busca en todas las posiciones, pero si es un array, se busca desde ***la posición ingresada (`desde`)*** sumado la **longitud** del `array` (`desde+array.length`), es decir, desde el final del array, restado el valor absoluto (o el opuesto) de `desde`.

La explicación sería la siguiente:

- Si la clase `Array` no tiene el método `includes`, lo agrega.
- El primer argumento de la función es el `valor`, es decir, `searchElement`.
- El segundo argumento es `desde`. Está comentado en el código, y sería `fromIndex` (*from index* significa *desde el índice*) o `arguments[1]`.

1. Le asigna a la variable `O` el `array`, que es `Object(this)`.
2. Asigna la longitud del `array` a `len`. Para esto usa `parseInt`. Si el resultado de `parseInt` da `NaN`, le asigna `0`.

La función `parseInt`, hace lo mismo que `Math.floor`, intenta buscar la parte entera de un número. Por ejemplo, `3.999` pasa a `3`. En caso de ingresar un *string* que no sea un número (`"z"`), devuelve `NaN`. En casos raros, puede considerarse un número, una cadena que tiene letras, por ejemplo, `"0x64"` es `100`.

Es raro que un array tenga como longitud algo que dé `NaN`, pero el código está hecho así, por las dudas de que llegara a ocurrir.

3. Si la longitud del `array` es `0`, devuelve `false`. Cuando pasa esto, significa que el `valor` no está incluido *desde* la posición ingresada hasta el final del `array`.
4. Asigna a la variable `n`, la posición `desde` donde se empieza a buscar. La posición es procesada por `parseInt`, y si el resultado es `NaN`, le asigna `0`, como sucedió anteriormente con `len`.

Esto significa que:

```
([2,3,4,5]).includes(3,2) //Devuelve false
([2,3,4,5]).includes(3,"z") //Devuelve true
```

Devuelve `true` porque `z` transformado a número es `0`.

- `3` no está incluido en el rango `<2,fin_array>`.
- `3` sí, está incluido en el rango `<0,fin_array>` (`0` es la transformación a entero de `"z"`).

La segunda parte del código se explicaría de la siguiente manera. Para entenderlo mejor, renombro `n` por `desde` y `len` por `longitud`.

1. Declara la variable `k`, que es la posición desde donde se quiere buscar dentro del array.
2. Si la posición `desde`, es mayor o igual a `0`, es decir, si se busca en una posición positiva en el `array`:

   - Entonces asigna a `k`, el valor de `desde`, es decir, busca desde la posición ingresada hasta el final del array.
   - En caso contrario, es decir, `desde` es negativo, le asigna a `k`, `principio+longitud`.

     - Si luego de hacer la suma, todavía da negativo, le asigna `0` a `k`, para poder buscar desde el comienzo del array, y no antes del comienzo (la función da por sentado que antes del comienzo no hay nada, lo cual no necesariamente es cierto).
3. Declara `currentElement`, que es el elemento actual que se compara con el `valor` buscado. Esta variable va cambiando a medida que va recorriendo el array. Es declarada fuera del `while`, aunque si hubiera sido declarada dentro, hubiera sido lo mismo, pero se hace así por si alguien quiere programar la función en un lenguaje de bajo nivel como *C*.
4. El `while` comprueba que la posición del elemento a comparar, es decir, `k`, sea menor a la `longitud` del array, para comparar el `valor` dentro del rango ingresado.

   4.1 El elemento actual es el *k-ésimo* valor del `array`.

   4.2 Si el elemento actual es igual al `valor` ingresado, devuelve `true`.

   - Si el elemento es diferente, además hace estas comprobaciones con `!==`, y en caso de que sean verdaderas las dos, devuelve `true`:
   - El elemento actual no es exactamente igual a sí mismo.
   - El valor buscado no es exactamente igual a sí mismo.
   - **Notas:** Si se ingresa un string `"4"`, entonces devuelve `false` si se busca el número `4` y no está en el array como un número. Un valor que no es igual a sí mismo es `NaN`.

   4.3. Aumenta en `1` a `k` dentro del `while`, que es la posición actual donde se busca.

5. Si dentro del `while` no hubo ningún elemento que sea igual al buscado, retorna `false`. Esto significa que el valor buscado no está dentro del rango en el `array`.

---

Para lograr el objetivo, yo hubiera programado la función de la siguiente manera.

Mi función lo que hace es buscar, no solo en el array, sino también en lugares anteriores al principio del array, en caso de que `posición` sea negativo.

Para crear un `array` que tenga valores en posiciones negativas, lo fabrico desde un objeto, luego le cambio la propiedad `__proto__` y le agrego la propiedad `length`.

```js
//Función propia que intenta hacer lo mismo que includes.

function incluye(array,valor,posición)
{
  posición+=posición<0?array.length:0
  for(var i=posición;i<array.length;i++)
  {
    if(array[i]==valor){return true}
  }
  return false
}

//Creando array mediante objeto.

var array={"-1":4,"0":6,"1":3,"2":6}
array.__proto__=[]
array.length=3

//Probando función.

var búsquedas=[
  [ 4,  5 ],  [ 4,  1 ],  [ 4, -5 ],
  [ 3,  5 ],  [ 3,  1 ],  [ 3, -5 ]
]
console.log("En [4]["+array+"] se busca: incluye | includes")
for(var i in búsquedas)
{
  var valor=búsquedas[i][0]
  var principio=búsquedas[i][1]
  console.log(
    valor +" desde la posición "+principio+": "
    +incluye(array,valor,principio)+" | "
    +array.includes(valor,principio)
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

te doy una breve explicación del código:

En la línea 4, obtiene la longitud del array pasado al generar un objeto del tipo Array, la variable `len` almacena ese valor entero.

Luego, se verifica el signo del segundo argumento, si es positivo, la variable `k` almacena el valor de ese argumento, sino, esa misma variable obtiene la posición del elemento relacionada con la longitud del array `len + n`.

Finalmente, se itera desde el elemento `k` hasta el final del array, verificando si el elemento `O[k]` corresponde con el buscado y retorna `true` en caso de ser iguales o si tanto `searchElement` como `currentElement` son del tipo `NaN`.

Saludos!